# How do I programmatically position an ImageView in AndroidStudio

Tags: java, android, xml, android-studio, imageview

I want to position my ImageView in Android Studio so it can be in the same place (ratio wise) throughout the many screen sizes of Android phones.

this is my code in `activity_main.xml`:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="com.slippysam.sooper_fly.slippysam.MainActivity"
android:background="@drawable/bgday">

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:maxHeight="40dp"
    android:maxWidth="40dp"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"

    android:src="@drawable/sam"
    android:id="@+id/samm"
    />
</RelativeLayout/>
```

and here is a function I tried using in my `Activity.java`

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

   positionSam();

}
public void positionSam(){
    final ImageView sam = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.samm);

    DisplayMetrics dm = getApplicationContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
    float dpHeight = dm.heightPixels / dm.density;
    float dpWidth = dm.widthPixels / dm.density;

    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lp = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) sam.getLayoutParams();
    lp.leftMargin = (int) ((dpWidth * 0.5));
    lp.topMargin = (int) ((dpHeight * 1.0555));
    sam.setLayoutParams(lp);
}
}
```

this function does indeed change the position of my ImageView however it's position still isn't concrete when I switch between products.

Comment: Please include the whole layout.

Comment: @ChrisWilson done :)

Comment: please specify position like gravity="center" or what ever you want of RelativeLayout. let me know if it works.

Comment: why do you want to set image view from the java file instead it you can set your image view in layout in your xml file easily.

Comment: @AbdulAleemAkhund I don't want to centre my ImageView I want it's height from the bottom to be 1/3 of the total screen.

Comment: @BhuvneshChasta Because I want a more flexible way of setting a location for my ImageView where, instead of setting the layout based off of pixels or inches; I can use fractions based off the screen's height and width to place it precisely where I need it to be in every screen size layout.

Comment: "I want it's height from the bottom to be 1/3 of the total screen" @ Frank Gully, you can use this code for it.             Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay(); int screenHeight = 1/3*(display.getHeight());lmageView.setMargins(0, 20, 0, screenHeight);

Comment: @BhuvneshChasta doesn't work :( everytime I compile it, the ImageView ends up at the top of the screen. Also `ImageView.setMargins();` isn't a resource apparently. So I used `ImageView.setBottom();` but still no luck. Also it tells me `display.getHeight` can be replaced by `0` because `.getHeight` is deprecated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

okay, so my first method was basically correct; I just needed to edit my `RelativeLayout` to this:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="0px"
android:paddingLeft="0px"
android:paddingRight="0px"
android:paddingTop="0px"
tools:context="com.slippysam.sooper_fly.slippysam.MainActivity"
android:background="@drawable/bgday">
```

changing the `paddingBottom` `paddingLeft` and etc. helps the function become more accurate in where I need the ImageView to be. I hope this reaches to anybody who needs it.

Answer (score 0):

In your layout (`RelativeLayout`) you need to specify where the `ImageView` should be placed.

You could try with the attribute `android:centerInParent="true"` for instance, so your layout file would look something like this:

```
<RelativeLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.slippysam.sooper_fly.slippysam.MainActivity"
    android:background="@drawable/bgday">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:maxHeight="40dp"
        android:maxWidth="40dp"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:centerInParent="true"
        android:src="@drawable/sam"
        android:id="@+id/samm" />

</RelativeLayout/>
```

By using `centerInParent="true"` you don't need to center the `ImageView` programmatically as you're doing it right now.
If you still want to do it programmatically, you can add a rule to your `LayoutParams` like this:

```
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lp = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) sam.getLayoutParams();
lp.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_IN_PARENT, RelativeLayout.TRUE);
sam.setLayoutParams(lp);
```

And then forget about setting the margin for the `ImageView`.

To use it programmatically, you will need to call your `positionSam()` method every time a new image is shown.